# IdentityServer4 юзер менджемент

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

У меня такой вопрос у меня есть проект WebApi. У него есть своя база данных в ней есть юзеры.
Я хочу использовать IdentityServer4 для аутентификации. Но я не понимаю как это должно работать.
Поидее Юзеры которые регистрируются с помощью IdentityServer должны храниться в отдельной базе данных.
Но как мне связать две эти баз данных?
У меня на проекте есть допустим какой-то продукт в котором используется юзер.

```
class Product
{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public User User {get;set;}
}
```

При регистрации, как я должен сохранять юзеров ?  Сохранять в базе данных проекта, и в базе данных IdentityServer ?

Comment: Данные в основной БД вяжутся только к ID учеток пользователей, а БД сервера авторизации хранит сами учетные данные, рядом с точно такими же ID. БД может быть общая, могут быть разные БД на одном БД-сервере, могут быть разные БД-серверы, здесь уж как вам больше нравится. Ну плюс лучше вопросы безопасности поизучать.